# I get exception when I try to update the pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

When I've tried to download a package from anaconda prompt. It notified me like in the below section.

"[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.1 -> 23.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip"

I've copied this command and copy pasted it to my anaconda prompt but I got an exception.

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 449, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 72, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 800, in install
    install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 731, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 648, in _install_wheel
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 436, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 429, in make
    return super().make(specification, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 425, in make    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 325, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 249, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yoato\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 404, in _get_launcher
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```

Then:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```